# Node not getting labelled during visualization and giving some ids instead in AgeViewer

Tags: apache-age

I have two files:

1st: City.csv:
[image]

2nd file: Mfr.csv

[image]

When I load both files into two separate graph the first graph for 1st file is label nicely with name field, but for 2nd file the graph is some random GIDs,
How can I solve this issue?

Query used:

```
 SELECT * from cypher('xyz', $$
        MATCH (V:Mfr)
        RETURN V
$$) as (V agtype);
```

Result: for 2nd file
[image]

Result: for 1st file
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on the blue label "Mfr", then it will appear some settings in a small bar below the drawn graph, there you will be able to change the names shown on the nodes from  to other properties.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem before when I didn’t explicitly defined the Uniqe ID for the labeling, the info of the node can be found when hovering, so to over come this you can specify the column “id” and add it to the database
Second, Why in the second column the 11th row seems wild?

SELECT load_labels_from_file('ABC', 'Label0', 'Mrf.csv', true, 'id');